# Pixel Qi screen on ubuntu

Tags: screen, backlight

I just installed Pixel Qi screen (PQ101WX01), but I can only control dimming of the screen. It doesn't become more readable in the sunlight. And if I go to sleep, screen becomes completely black.

How do I shut down backlight in ubuntu (13 or more newer) and switch Pixel Qi screen mode of operation to readable in the sun?

Here's the quote from Clover's SunBook having PixelQi display: "In daylight, the backlight can be turned off completely, cutting the power consumption, extending battery life, and reducing eyestrain. Reflective mode provides 1024 x 600 resolution in black & white." This is the feature I am searching for.

EDIT: Thank you for the answers and help. After talking to the Pixel Qi company, it seams like the screen I got was a fake one, so be careful when ordering off ebay.

Comment: Hi, I'm also very interested in PixelQi screens, can you please add the info @s3hh requested? I'm ready to start a bounty for this question if the first answer will not work and you are still here.

Comment: would you mind telling us what the seller and supposed model was, so we can try to avoid the scam?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have one of these yet, but my understanding is that dimming it completely should simply leave the black and white e-ink display.

Did you buy the display separately?  If so which laptop did you put it in?  Or, did you in fact buy the sunbook?

Anyway, perhaps you are actually changing the contrast instead of brightness.  My suggestion would be to run the following command in a terminal:

```sh
find /sys -name "bright*"
```

This should return a few files, including something like
`/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/0000:01:00.0/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness`. If you read the file (`cat /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/0000:01:00.0/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness`) it should give the current brightness (mine says '8'), and you can turn brightness completely off by doing:

```sh
echo 0 | sudo tee -a /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/0000:01:00.0/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
```

Then obviously you can reset it by doing:

```sh
echo 8 | sudo tee -a /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/0000:01:00.0/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
```

Hopefully that will get you what you want.  Please keep us informed.  I'm very interested in getting something like this myself :)

Comment: Acer Aspire One D270, that is the laptop I got this screen installed. I bought the mentioned display separately, I bought it of reseller in Taiwan on ebay. I don't own the actual SunBook.
I can read on Pixel Qi website [pdf](http://www.pixelqi.com/yahoo_site_admin/assets/docs/PQ101WX01_20121029V10.306201705.pdf) for the "This module also supports two low power modes: a transflective mode and a reflective mode with lower color."

Comment: Thanks for the tips which works in dimming the screen, just like when I use the function keys. So I was changing the brightness from the start. Unfortunately, the screen hasn't changed the mode of operation.

Comment: Hm, I do know that when Make was selling kits they only guaranteed it with the samsung n130 and lenovo s10-2  (I have an s10-3 I was hoping to one day test with).  It's possible it's not compatible, or that you got a bum unit...  Just to be sure, could you do a "find /sys > /tmp/syslist 2>&1" and pastebin the result and give us the paste here?  I've never heard of a toggle for activating the reflective part, but if there is one it should show up in that list.

Comment: After googling a little more (sitting annoyed outside without a pixelqi :) the display you bought is *not* the same one that was purported to work with the s10-2 and the samsungs.  That one had a lower resolution for one thing, of 1024x600.  That isn't to say yours won't work, just that i've seen zero reports of it working with linux.  See for instance http://hardforum.com/showthread.php?t=1814709